# Proxy to rewrite responses during mobile testing

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

I am testing a mobile application. There are situations where I would like like to alter the response coming from the server that talks to the app.

I have a phone (Android) connected to computer running Cucumber tests. I would like to proxy the responses coming into the phone and change them a bit so I can test more scenarios.

Any good ideas?

[phone] --> "give me your info" --> [server]

[server] --> "here is the info" ---> [ruby proxy] ---> "here is the ALTERED info" ---> [phone]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Charles proxy app (http://www.charlesproxy.com) with map remote function (http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/).